# Previous UITableViewCell repeating after header change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating my own personal budget app that is taking data such as store, money spent, date, etc. onto a table. I'm sorting the entries by `strftime %W`. My dictionary of the data sorted by `%W` is:

```
_results =

{ 
  46 =  (
            {
              DATE = "11/13/2019";
              ID = 10;
              PLACE = Test;
              PRICE = "43.23";
            },
            {
              DATE = "11/15/2019";
              ID = 11;
              PLACE = OneMore;
              PRICE = "32.12";
            }
       );
  47 =  (
            {
              DATE = "11/18/2019";
              ID = 12;
              PLACE = Kroger;
              PRICE = "54.32";
            }
        );
}
```

My UITableView setup is:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [_resultsTitles count];
}
```

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[_resultsTitles objectAtIndex:section] stringValue];
}
```

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
//     return self.arrFoodInfo.count;
    NSNumber *sectionTitle = [_resultsTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *sectionAnimals = [_results objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    return [sectionAnimals count];
}
```

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 60.0;
}
```

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Dequeue the cell.
    static NSString *identifier = @"idCellRecord";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }

    // Set the loaded data to the appropriate cell labels.
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ | $%@", [[self.arrFoodInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"PLACE"], [[self.arrFoodInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"PRICE"]];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@", [[self.arrFoodInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"DATE"]];

    return cell;
}
```

When running my app, the table headers are correct but when an entry is "added" in the next section, the first entry is duplicated.
[image: Picture of repeated entry]

Is there anyway to get the correct entries showing grouped by the week number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve by adding the following into `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
NSNumber *sectionTitle = [_resultsTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *sectionResults = [_results objectForKey:sectionTitle];
NSString *cellData = [sectionResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Now looks like:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Dequeue the cell.
    static NSString *identifier = @"idCellRecord";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }

    NSNumber *sectionTitle = [_resultsTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionResults = [_results objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    NSString *cellData = [sectionResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Set the loaded data to the appropriate cell labels.
    cell.textLabel.text = [cellData valueForKey:YourValHere];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where **self.arrFoodInfo** come from?

I guess self.arrFoodInfo have this data:

```
(
        {
          DATE = "11/13/2019";
          ID = 10;
          PLACE = Test;
          PRICE = "43.23";
        },
        {
          DATE = "11/15/2019";
          ID = 11;
          PLACE = OneMore;
          PRICE = "32.12";
        }
        {
          DATE = "11/18/2019";
          ID = 12;
          PLACE = Kroger;
          PRICE = "54.32";
        }
   );
```

The **indexPath.row** in each section is different, when move to next section, **indexPath.row** will restart to **zero**.

You should update the way binding data or restructure self.arrFoodInfo list, example like this in JSON:

```
[
  [
    {
      "DATE": "11/13/2019",
      "ID": 10,
      "PLACE": "Test",
      "PRICE": "43.23"
    },
    {
      "DATE": "11/15/2019",
      "ID": 11,
      "PLACE": "OneMore",
      "PRICE": "32.12"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "DATE": "11/18/2019",
      "ID": 12,
      "PLACE": "Kroger",
      "PRICE": "54.32"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: I was able to solve this. Please check my response above. Thank you!